# More comprehensive documentation of markdown available for comment boxes

Tags: support, status-completed, comments, markdown

Is there a comprehensive list of what markdown elements can be used in comment boxes? I only recently discovered that the shorter format for links actually works (whereas the longer format doesn't), and now I'm wondering what else we can put in comment boxes. Here's what I've gotten so far, is there more?

**Links:**

```
[link text](http://example.com)
```

**Bold/italic**

```
**bold**  _italic_
```

**Code snippets**

```
`code`
```

It doesn't seem like there's any way to get bulleted lists, etc. but I feel like I might be missing something, since I lived for months thinking you could only paste links as-is without being able to specify the text displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Text Formatting Now Allowed In Comments (List of Proven and Disproven Abilities)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities) on MSO for a list of formatting that works in comments.